# Нужна помощь в настройке swap под Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

Имеется домашний ПК с 4гб оперативной памяти и Manjaro Linux KDE x64 на борту. В некоторых случаях оперативной памяти не хватает и вся система просто зависает, пока часть памяти не переместится в своп. SWAp у меня в виде раздела 1.9гб в самом конце таблицы разделов. Собственно проблема - как убрать зависание системы? Как заставить ядро linux при нехватки памяти не вешать систему намертво? В системном мониторе видно, что иксы, плазма и тд и тп висят в ожидании на диске, а процессор загружен на 100%. При чем в своп перемещается незначительное колличество страниц: от 1мб до 40мб, в исключительных случаях более 100мб, а система зависает относительно надолго от нескольких секунд до нескольких минут.

Comment: при таком размере оперативной памяти, свап должен быть хотя бы 8 гигов. И ещё, тестируйте при закрытом хроме. На таком объеме памяти он выжирает ее всю и тогда система ложиться. Лечить добавлением планки.

Comment: Ещё добавлю, что кеды очень много жрут. Можно попробовать XFCE или LXDE.

Comment: Использую Firefox. Нехватка памяти происходит когда запущена игра Minecraft, которая выжирает почти 2гб памяти. Вопрос не в том, чтобы сократить потребляемую память, а в том, чтобы ОС не вешала систему при отправке данных в своп.

Comment: Linux и не вешает систему при отправке данных в swap. Также 2 гига swap на minecraft это мало, полное зависание возможно наблюдается иза нехватки swap, попробуйте врубить диспетчер задач и нагрузить систему, понаблюдайте за swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо подрегулировать параметр swappiness, который отвечает за количество  заполненной памяти, после которого начинается активное использование swap файла :

`cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

Наверняка будет число 60. Чем меньше число, тем больше памяти можно использовать. Рекомендую поставить 10. Временно это можно сделать выполнив в консоли:

`sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10`

Постоянно величину можно задать в файл `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Далее перезагрузка или `swapoff -a` и `swapon -a`.

Идеально было бы использовать SSD диск. Предполагаю что сейчас используется SATA.

Comment: Как ни странно "cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness" вернул 1. Можно дробные числа туда писать? Какие нибуть 100мб критичны

Comment: Можно и 0 поставить

Answer (score 0):

При объеме RAM 4Gb [рекомендуемый размер раздела для Swap должен быть минимум 4Gb](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-ppc.html):

```
Amount of RAM in the system   Recommended swap space         Recommended swap space 
                                                             if allowing for hibernation
---------------------------   ----------------------------   ---------------------------
2GB of RAM or less            2 times the amount of RAM      3 times the amount of RAM
2GB to 8GB of RAM             Equal to the amount of RAM     2 times the amount of RAM
8GB to 64GB of RAM            0.5 times the amount of RAM    1.5 times the amount of RAM
```

Comment: красивая таблица. приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на первоисточник.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-ppc.html#id4394007